# Am I correct to say that ladder operators have complex eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

From the definition: $$\left. \begin{array} { l } { \hat { L } _ { + } = \hat { L } _ { x } + i \hat { L } _ { y } } \\ { \hat { L } _ { - } = \hat { L } _ { x } - i \hat { L } _ { y } } \end{array} \right.$$
We know that $\hat { L } _ { x }$ and $\hat { L } _ { y }$ have real eigenvalues, thus $\hat { L } _ { + }$ and $\hat { L } _ { - }$ should have complex eigenvalues.

Am I correct to say so? Is there any physical meaning in this?

I do know that $\hat { L } _ { + }$ and $\hat { L } _ { - }$ do produce real coefficients, but only for a different state (the "next/previous" states of $\hat { L } _ { z }$. What I wonder is what happen to the same state :D

Comment: Try playing with Pauli matrices.  The eigenvalues of $L_{+}$ and $L_{-}$ are real but no independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $L_+$ and $L_-$ are not hermitian it is perfectly reasonable, as a possibility, that they might have complex eigenvalues.

However, for these specific operators, this is not the case. You can check this explicitly by taking the well-known relation
$$
L_+|l,m\rangle = \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m+1)}|l,m+1\rangle,
$$
expressing it as an explicit matrix, and taking the eigenvalues. The structure of the matrix is of the form
$$
L_+ = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  & \\
\sqrt{2l} & 0 & \\
 & \sqrt{4l-2} & 0\\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots &  & \\
 &  &  &\sqrt{4l-2} & 0 \\
 &  &  &  &\sqrt{2l} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where all the empty entries are zero, and that means that the characteristic polynomial can be calculated fairly simply, using row-reduction techniques, to the bare expression
\begin{align}
\det(L_+-\lambda) & = \det\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda &  & \\
\sqrt{2l} & -\lambda & \\
 & \sqrt{4l-2} & -\lambda\\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots &  & \\
 &  &  &\sqrt{4l-2} & -\lambda \\
 &  &  &  &\sqrt{2l} & -\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}
\\ & = (-1)^{2l+1}\lambda^{2l+1}.
\end{align}
In other words: **the only eigenvalue of $L_+$ is zero**, with multiplicity $2l+1$.

As for the eigenvectors of that eigenvalue, there is only one:
$$
L_+|l,l\rangle = 0.
\tag{$*$}
$$
The rest of the matrix is one big [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix), for which there are provably no more eigenvectors than the base case in $(*)$ above. In fact, $L_z$ is *almost* already in Jordan-Block form in the $|l,m\rangle$ basis, and all you need to do is to take a non-unit-normalized multiple of the $|l,m\rangle$ basis to bring $L_z$ into explicit Jordan-block form,
$$
L_+ = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  &  &  &  & \\
1 & 0 & \\
 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots &  & \\
 &  &  & 1 & 0 \\
 &  &  &  & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues are $0$.  The simplest way to see this is to suppose you work in a finite dimensional space of size $2\ell+1$.  Then for any state 
$\vert \ell m\rangle $
you have $L_+^k\vert\psi\rangle=0$ for $k\ge 2\ell+1$ since 
$$
L_+^{2\ell+1}\vert \ell,-\ell\rangle=0\, ,\qquad
L_+^{2\ell+1}\vert \ell, -\ell+1\rangle=0\, \ldots
$$
i.e. you can raise a state at most $2\ell$ times before you kill it.
Now suppose 
$$
\vert \psi\rangle=\sum_m c_m\vert\ell m\rangle
$$
is such that $L_+\vert\psi\rangle=\lambda\vert\psi\rangle$.  Apply $L_+$ again, and then again and then apply it $2\ell+1$ times to find
$$
L_+^{2\ell+1}\vert\psi\rangle= \lambda^{2\ell+1}\vert\psi\rangle 
=\sum_m c_m L_+^{2\ell+1}\vert\ell m\rangle=0
$$ 
from which one must conclude $\lambda=0$.  The same argument can be make to show that eigenvalues of $\hat L_-$ are $0$.  Given that the eigenvalues are $0$ one must then find states $\vert \psi\rangle$ such that
$L_+\vert\psi\rangle=0$.  The only state that satisfies this is (up to normalization) $\vert \ell,\ell\rangle$.

This is *unlike* the situation for harmonic oscillator, where states are never killed by the raising operator $\hat a^\dagger$ because the space contains states $\vert n\rangle$ for any $n\ge 0$, i.e. the space is infinite dimensional.  It is moreover possible to find *some* states which are eigenstates of $\hat a$: these are the famous [coherent states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states) and they are a sum containing all $\vert n\rangle$ state.

Answer (score -3):

Eigenvectors of ladder operators are called "[coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states)". Quoting the Wikipedia article:

> Since $\hat{a}$ is not hermitian, $\alpha$ is, in general, a complex number.

So, yeah, you are correct to say that *in general* the eigenvalues are complex (yet it is possible to have some coherent states with real eigenvalues).

Since that answer seems controversial...
Here is a peer-reviewed paper reference on the subject for the angular momentum ladder operators:

[*D.Bhaumik et al 1975 J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 8 1868*](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/8/12/003/pdf)

Comment: OP is asking about the angular momentum ladder operators, not about the bosonic creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm not answering specifically about the bosonic creation and annihilation operators. I'm talking about ladder operators in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator

Comment: The Bhaumik et al. paper that you reference provides coherent states with complex eigenvalues for the $I_-$ and $K_-$ operators which act as ladder operators on the *total* angular momentum $l$, and which have very different properties to the $L_\pm$ operators that OP is asking about. You can go hunting for references that construct complex-eigenvalue eigenvectors for $L_\pm$ all you want and come back when you find such a reference, of course. (Hint: you'd be wasting your time. $L_\pm$ can easily be shown to have zero as their one and only eigenvalue.)

Comment: This is not correct. Coherent states are only eigenvectors of the lowering operators in the harmonic oscillator case.  Otherwise one must use a different definition of coherent state : the most common definition is by Perelomov and gives the coherent state as a lowest weight state translated by a group operation.  This coindices with the definition of CS for the harmonic oscillator and works for angular momentum and other cases.